# Incorporating Signature with Permute for symmetric groups

Tags: permutation

Let
$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) := \frac{x_1^{-3} x_2^{-2} x_3^{-1}}{(1 - x_1^2) (1 -x_1^2 x_2^2) (1 - x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2) (1 - x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2 x_4^2)}.$$
I am trying to compute
$$\sum_{w\in S_4} (-1)^{\overline{w}} w(f),$$
where $\overline{w}$ is the parity of the permutation element $w$ (it's the number of transpositions when $w$  is written as a product of such), and $w$ is acting $f$ via the indices of the variables $x_i$.

I have this code

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := (x1^-3 x2^-2 x3^-1)/((1 - x1^2) (1 - x1^2 x2^2) (1 - x1^2 x2^2 x3^2)(1 - x1^2 x2^2 x3^2 x4^2));

Total[Permute[g @@ Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 4], #] & /@GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]] /. g -> f]
```

but I am not sure how to incorporate the `Signature[]` of some permutation element so that it coincides with `Permute` in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Signature` wants to operate on expressions and interprets each `Cycles[...]` object as a list of length 1. You can convert `Cycles` objects to list with `PermutationsList` and apply `Signature` afterwards.

```
With[{xx = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 4]},

 Sum[
  Signature[PermutationList[σ, 4]] f @@ Permute[xx, σ],
  {σ, GroupElements[SymmetricGroup[4]]}
  ]

 ]
```

Alternatively, you may skip the group hokus-pokus and use `Permutations`:

```
With[{xx = Array[Subscript[x, #] &, 4]},

 Sum[
  Signature[p] f @@ xx[[p]],
  {p, Permutations[Range[4]]}
  ]

 ]
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you. This is very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.